# Помогите найти ошибку в методе

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть массив заполненный числами от 1 до 100 с пропущенным числом 46, путем сложения первого и последнего элемента идет поиск пропущенного элемента, по неизвестной мне причине ничего не работает, переменная end не уменьшается.

```
public static void main(String ...args) {
    int[] sor={};
    sor=init(sor, 99, 46);

    System.out.println(searchBin(sor));
}

public static int[] init(int [] ar,int lenght,int val){
    ar= new int[lenght];
    for(int i1=0,i=1;i<=ar.length+1;i1++,i++){
        if(i==val) {
            i1--;
            val=0;
            continue;
        }
        ar[i1]=i;
    }
    return ar;
}

public static int searchBin(int[] ar){
    int start=ar[0];//1
    int end=ar[ar.length-1];//100
    int sum=start+end;//101
    int r=sum;//101

    while(r==sum){//true
        start++;//2
        end--;//99
        start= ar[start-1];//2
        end  = ar[end-1];//здесь значение возвращается на с 99 на 100

        r=start+end;//101

    }

    return start;
}
```

Comment: Название `searchBin` подразумевает бинарный поиск?

Comment: в перспективе да, пока я прорабатываю такой вариант поиска, точнее проработал, но так и не понял момент, который я описал ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно переписать метод init, он не использует входной массив, меняет один из параметров цикла внутри цикла, и логика слишком запутана.

Подумайте на бумаге для маленького массива, как всё должно быть.
Пусть длина = 5 и исключается число `val=3`

```
i    0  1  2  3  4
ar   1  2  4  5  6
```

Т.е. достаточно для малых индексов записывать `i+1`, а для больших `i+2`, начиная с индекса `i-1`. Если в java есть тернарный оператор, цикл вообще будет в две строчки.

```
public static int[] init(int lenght,int val){
    int[] ar = new int[lenght];
    for(int i=0; i<ar.length;i++){
        if(i<val-1) 
            ar[i] = i + 1;
        else
            ar[i] = i + 2;
    }
    return ar;
}
```

А вот метод поиска в таком виде полноценно работать не будет. Если даже нашли пару, то нужно ещё проверять, какой элемент из пары нарушает порядок.

Название, вообще говоря, подразумевает **бинарный поиск**.
Если опираться на то, что входной массив сформирован корректно, то бинарный поиск, который будет искать самый левый элемент после разрыва, будет довольно прост:

```
public static int searchBin(int[] ar){
    int l = 0;
    int r = ar.length-1;
    int m;

    while( l < r) {
        m = (l + r) >>> 1;   //среднее значение
        if (ar[m] == m + 2)   //мы в правой части
             r = m;
        else
             l = m + 1;
    }
    return l + 1;
  }
```

Рабочий [код тут](https://ideone.com/5nhV5s)

Answer (score 1):

У вас была ошибка в алгоритме. Вот рабочий код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sor={};
    sor=init(sor, 99, 43);

    System.out.println(searchBin(sor));
}

public static int[] init(int [] ar,int lenght,int val){
    ar= new int[lenght];
    for(int i1=0,i=1;i<=ar.length+1;i1++,i++){
        if(i==val) {
            i1--;
            val=0;
            continue;
        }
        ar[i1]=i;
    }
    return ar;
}

public static int searchBin(int[] ar){
    int start=ar[0];//1
    int end=ar[ar.length-1];//100
    int sum=start+end;//101
    int r=sum;//101

    while(r==sum){//true
        start++;//2
        end--;//99
        start= ar[start-1];//2
        end  = ar[end-2];// поставил -2 вместо -1

        r=start+end;//101

    }

    return start-1; // поставил -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть предположение что в строке:

> end--;

нужно использовать префиксную форму, поскольку мы хотим использовать значение сразу.

Comment: Это java, js это другой язык.

Comment: Конечно же я понимаю что языки разные) Мб поможет ,если это работает  также как и в JS и если я вообще правильно понял что происходит.

Comment: Ошибку я нашел в строке при end=99`; end  = ar[end-1];` единицу я поменял на двойку и заработало. Но честно говоря я не понимаю как так получается end=ar[end-1] при значении по индексу ar[98]= 99, он дает 100